# Unzip a zip using zipArchive in objective C

Tags: objective-c, zip

Here is my code:

```
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Users/DivyaDinesh/Downloads/d1.zip" ofType:@"zip"];
    NSString *unzipDir = @"Users/DivyaDinesh/Downloads/d1";
    ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [zipArchive UnzipOpenFile: @"Users/DivyaDinesh/Downloads/d1.zip" Password:@"123456"];
    [zipArchive UnzipFileTo:@"Users/DivyaDinesh/Downloads/d1/" overWrite:YES];
    [zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
    [zipArchive release];
    NSLog(@"finished");
}
```

the log is showing correct number of files in the zip archive, but its not extracting the files to the path specified.

these are the imports which i gave

```
#import "zip.h"
#import "ZipArchive.h"
```

Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if UnzipFileTo: returns YES or NO. My guess is that you have no write permission to this directory.

Comment: well sort of, when i changed it to ` [zipArchive UnzipFileTo:@"Users/DivyaDinesh/Downloads" overWrite:YES];` it worked, then i created a folder via code and tried the same. it works thanks